# What analysis is needed for AG?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, soft-question

My question:

> On what level do I need to know (complex/real) analysis or diff. geometry to study algebraic geometry from  Hartshorne? And AG in general?

Context: 
I will be taken a course in Elliptic Curves from J.S. Milne's Book(lecture notes published) this fall followed by a course in AG from  Hartshorne's book and want to do some preliminary reading this summer. My algebra and topology is sufficient, but have no analysis background futher than a introductory course on real analysis for 1 semester.

Comment: The most useful results you will need in algebraic geometry, at least for motivational purposes, are the implicit function theorem and its avatars: constant rank theorem, local diffeomorphism theorem, ...By the way, Hawthorne is a great American novelist but the great American algebraic geometer you probably mean is Hartshorne.

Comment: I have corrected it.

Comment: The main text of Hartshorne does not need any analysis whatsoever... but it may be difficult to appreciate what is going on, as Georges Elencwajg said.

Comment: Strange, the AG course states as prerequisites: "some Geometry (e.g., the notion of a differentiable variety)." And on J.S. Milne's page says:"It assumes only a knowledge of the basic algebra, complex analysis, and topology usually taught in advanced undergraduate or first-year graduate courses."

Comment: If you haven't done some differential geometry, then the notion of tangent space or smooth variety will probably be somewhat mysterious. But you don't _need_ to know differential geometry, because the definitions in algebraic geometry are purely algebraic!